# Hide Selected Item in vuetify v-select

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'am using Vuetify v-select.

How can I disable showing items that are selected in the v-select.

```
<v-select
          v-model="e6"
          :items="states"
          label="Select"
          multiple
          hint="Pick your favorite states"
          :persistent-hint="true"
          dense
          outlined
          :single-line="true"
          solo
          value=""
        ></v-select>
```

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/yoeko/pen/wvWXORE)

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by hide? remove it from the list?

Comment: remove the elements that appear in the the select itself after select the items i want

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring how to go about this? Is there a slot that I have a reference to in v-select that will help me accomplish this?

Comment: @frlzjosh Here is the solution i found in the documentation https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/#selection